# Mongoose: if object is present, increment value, if not push into array

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

folks, I have the following model:

```
articles: [
    {
      _id: {
        type: ObjectId,
        ref: "Article"
      },
      amount: {
        type: Number
      }
    }
  ]
```

the idea is to find if an article is present in the array, if so, then increment the amount, otherwise push into the array the values.

Currently, I'm using the following code, but I'm sure there is a way to do it just with one **findandupdate**.

```
function(warehouse, article, amount) {
Warehouse.findOne({
  _id: warehouse,
  "articles._id": article
})
  .then(function(found) {
    if (found) {
      return Warehouse.findOneAndUpdate(
        {
          _id: warehouse,
          "articles._id": article
        },
        {
          $inc: { "articles.$.amount": amount }
        }
      );
    }
    return Warehouse.findOneAndUpdate(
      {
        _id: warehouse
      },
      {
        $push: {
          articles: {
            _id: article,
            amount: amount,
            serialized: false
          }
        }
      }
    );
  })
```

**Edit:**

I'm using Neil suggestion, since I don't need the doc returned from this query.

So here is the bulkwrite:

```
 Warehouse.bulkWrite(
  [
    {
      updateOne: {
        filter: { _id: warehouse, "articles._id": article },
        update: {
          $inc: {
            "articles.$.amount": amount
          }
        }
      }
    },
    {
      updateOne: {
        filter: { _id: warehouse },
        update: {
          $addToSet: {
            articles: {
              _id: article,
              amount: amount,
              serialized: true
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ],
```

Somehow, the second update is always executed, even if its an $addToSet. Any ideas of how to avoid this behavior?

Comment: Not with `.findOneAndUpdate()` because that particular method is meant to "return" the document that is updated. You **can** do it in "one call" using [`.bulkWrite()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.bulkWrite), but of course the very nature of the method is that it does not return a document. You should rather question *"Do I really need the document returned?"* and then of course the question should then be *"Can I live with doing the `.findOne()` **after** the `.bulkWrite()` is complete?"*. And that should determine what you need to do.

Comment: @NeilLunn I do not need the return of the doc. Can you show me how to do a bulkWrite with the scenario that I'm asking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using Neil Lunn suggestion, since I don't need the doc returned from this query.

So here is the bulkwrite:

```
Warehouse.bulkWrite(
  [
    {
      updateOne: {
        filter: { _id: warehouse, "articles._id": article },
        update: {
          $inc: {
            "articles.$.amount": amount
          }
        }
      }
    },
    {
      updateOne: {
        filter: { _id: warehouse,
                  "articles._id": { $exists: false }},
        update: {
          $addToSet: {
            articles: {
              _id: article,
              amount: amount,
              serialized: true
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ],
```

Somehow, the second update is always executed, even if its an $addToSet, thats why I added the filter: "articles._id": { $exists: false }. Any ideas of how to avoid this behavior?

Comment: You actually mean `{ _id: warehouse, "articles._id": { $ne: article } }`, since `$exists` is not a sufficient check of anything more than there already being at least one array item present. But otherwise this is exactly what you should be doing. You should note that in the `nMatched` and `nUpdated` results of the response object will then begin to differ from the number of instructions in the "batch".